# everything is okay unless I press the backspace key, then I have viewed the file and strings are not for human reading

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, file-io, fopen

If I have made a wrong letter and I wanted to deleted by hitting the backspace key, It keeps printing a language that can not be read by a human.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h> 

void main(void)
{
    FILE *poointer;
    poointer= fopen("TestingXX.txt","w"); 
    char ch;
    
     while ( (ch=getche()) != '\r') 
        {
            putc(ch,poointer);                                
        }

    fclose(poointer);

}
```

Comment: You might try the standard `getchar` function.

Comment: You press backspace and ch is backspace and then you put the backspace into the file. If you want to delete the last thing from the file instead, then you have to make your program do that - it's not automatically.

Comment: When using the functions from the C standard library (e.g. `getchar`, `fgets`), then on most platforms, your program will only receive the input after the user has pressed the `ENTER` key. This allows the user to make corrections to the line before pressing the `ENTER` key, but not afterwards. However, when using functions from `conio.h` such as `getche`, your program will receive the input immediately. Therefore, if you want to allow the user to make corrections to the input by using the backspace key, then you will have to program that yourself.

Comment: Try `while ( (ch=getche()) != '\n')`.